# BreezeControllerAttribute exception: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

When I make a call to an API an error is displayed:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.",

### Code

I have a base controller for my APIs

```
[BreezeNHController]
public class baseApiController<T> : ApiController
    where T : class, IEntity
{
    public IRepository<T> Repositorio { get; private set; }

    [HttpGet, BreezeNHQueryable(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All, PageSize = 20)]
    public IQueryable<T> Get()
    {
        return Repositorio.All();
    }

    // ..
}
```

And implementation:

```
[BreezeController, Authorize]
public class usuariosController : baseApiController<User>
{
    public usuariosController(IUserRepository repositorio)
        : base(repositorio)
    { }
}
```

Url: GET `/api/usuarios` throw a exeption!

But my DDL is in reference:

[image]

### Full response errror:

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "The type initializer for 'Breeze.WebApi.BreezeControllerAttribute' threw an exception.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.TypeInitializationException",
    "StackTrace": "   at Breeze.WebApi.BreezeControllerAttribute.Initialize(HttpControllerSettings settings, HttpControllerDescriptor descriptor)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor..ctor(HttpConfiguration configuration, String controllerName, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.InitializeControllerInfoCache()\r\n   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()\r\n   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()\r\n   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()",
    "InnerException": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.",
        "ExceptionType": "System.IO.FileNotFoundException",
        "StackTrace": "   at Breeze.WebApi.JsonFormatter.Create()\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.BreezeControllerAttribute..cctor()"
    }
}
```

### Attempts

In the package manger console, run the command `Add-BindingRedirect`.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Found strange is not pointing to the 4.0. Can it be the problem? If yes, why `Add-BindingRedirect` did not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most definitely a binding redirect issue. I advice you copy the entire `<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">` content from a fresh ASP.NET MVC 4 project to your web.config file. This happens to me occasionally and refreshing the messed up bindings fixes the issue.