# Getting exception System.Web.Http in VS2013 using breeze?

Tags: asp.net, breeze

I am trying to create the HotTowel Sample application from Jhon Papa using Breeze and AngularJS. I have installed all the required packages and before installing **Breeze.WebApi** package everything works fine but after i installed this package then i am getting this below exception on WebApiRoute configuration method.

```
<ExceptionMessage>
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's 
manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 
0x80131040)
```

I have referenced the **System.Web.Http** dll to project but with latest 5.0.0 version.

Comment: Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426306/breezecontrollerattribute-exception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net ?

Comment: i think its bit different than mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do a binding redirect to point to new assemblies and see if it works.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Where do i need to add this configuration? in `web.config` or somewhere else

Comment: It would be part of your web.config. `<configuration><runtime>.....`. Check your existing config, it may already have this section.

Answer (score 0):

This was likely a result of trying to use the new Microsoft WebApi2 nuget packages in VS 2013.  Previously Breeze did not support these.

As of now, Breeze 1.4.5 has support for Microsoft's ASP.NET WebApi 2 and Entity Framework 6. Please see http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download.